# Date Fields - Seeing Current Value and Setting New Value

Tags: dates

**Scenario:**
User needs to know the current value before they set a new value for the date fields.
User can also clear the current date and set it to None (no date). I need a more intuitive design and would also like to hear others feedback.

**Concept Mock** 
Find a couple of concept mocks below.

Concept 1

[image]

Concept 2

[image]

Comment: Maybe take concept 2 and add an _Clear_ icon (like an X)

Comment: @bdimag that is exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Thanks. But I dont want the user to be confused with Clear and Reset :(

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping it simple where you just provide a date value and provide an option to edit it. This informs the user that he can edit the current value and when not editing this is the selected value

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3QSBT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Facebook uses this approach where it shows the current setting and allows you to change it by clicking on the edit option

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mervin. But I am already in the edit page. So not sure if adding additional edit links will be useful.